# Workaround to build and install SAP Commerce, Composable Storefront >5.0 on Windows - '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, npm, yarnpkg, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

During the local build and installation of "SAP Composable Storefront" on my Windows computer, following the video of Mateusz Ostafil ([Youtube Link How to build and install SAP Commerce, Composable Storefront 6.0 (SAP Spartacus 6.0)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvG-JimSEOA&ab_channel=CloudflightPoland%28formerDivante%29))

I ran into the error mentioned in the comments:

```
[build:schematics] 
[build:schematics] > storefrontapp@0.0.0 build:schematics
[build:schematics] > npm --prefix projects/schematics run build
[build:schematics]
[build:user] 
[build:user] > storefrontapp@0.0.0 build:user
[build:user] > npm --prefix feature-libs/user run build:schematics && ng build user --configuration production
[build:user]
[build:schematics] 
[build:schematics] > @spartacus/schematics@6.0.3 build
[build:schematics] > npm run clean && npm --prefix ../../ run generate:deps && ../../node_modules/.bin/tsc -p ./tsconfig.schematics.json    
[build:schematics]
[build:user]
[build:user] > @spartacus/user@6.0.3 build:schematics
[build:user] > npm run clean:schematics && ../../node_modules/.bin/tsc -p ./tsconfig.schematics.json
[build:user]
[build:schematics] 
[build:schematics] > @spartacus/schematics@6.0.3 clean
[build:schematics] > ../../node_modules/.bin/rimraf "index.js*" "index.d.ts" "src/**/*.js" "src/**/*.js.map" "src/**/*.d.ts"
[build:schematics]
[build:user]
[build:user] > @spartacus/user@6.0.3 clean:schematics
[build:user] > ../../node_modules/.bin/rimraf "schematics/**/*.js" "schematics/**/*.js.map" "schematics/**/*.d.ts"
[build:user]
[build:schematics] '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[build:schematics] operable program or batch file.
[build:user] '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[build:user] operable program or batch file.
[build:schematics] npm run build:schematics exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[build:user] npm run build:user exited with code 1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I found an alternative solution to the problem, since Windows does not recognize the "/" in the paths of the different package.json files, so in the files of each library I replaced the slash "/" with: "\".

This allows the libraries to be built using the `yarn build:libs` or `npm run build:libs` command.

Example image of how the replaced "/" look:
[screenshot asm modified package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIw1c.png)

If anyone knows any other solution or a better alternative, don't hesitate to leave it in the comments.

Comment: I tried with release/6.0.x and it worked. Check your OS, node and angular cli version.